# Specify custom subdomain to all GCP resources in a project

Tags: squarespace, google-cloud-dns, aws-route53

I have a domain purchased from squarespace, let's say its name is `mydomain.com`. Then, I have created an organization on Google Cloud with the same domain verified through a TXT record.

My domain will be used by multiple resources in GCP and AWS. So, I want to specify the subdomain `gcp.mydomain.com` to be used with all the services in GCP, and its subdomains like `app.gcp.mydomain.com` and others to be controlled in Google Cloud DNS. The same applies for AWS.

What should I do in squarespace side to configure that all the requests that come to `*.gcp.mydomain.com` to be handled by GCP Cloud DNS, and all the requests that come to `*.aws.mydomain.com` to be handled by AWS DNS Service? So, I want squarespace to act as an interface only and the DNS service in the destination platform is the one that handles its DNS records separately.

Comment: You can configure any subdomain you want in DNS and configure DNS resource records to resolve hostnames to A, AAAA, and CNAME records. However, there is nothing in GCP or AWS to make that a default. You must configure DNS as you require for each hostname. You can use a wildcard `*.subdomain.example.com` to send all subdomain traffic to one host, list of hosts, or service, but again you must configure that in DNS.

Comment: I know I should configure each host in DNS, but I want to do this in GCP Cloud DNS not in squarespace DNS.

Comment: Squarespace is your registrar. You can use any public DNS server you control. Create a hosted zone for your domain in Cloud DNS and update your NS (name server) resource records to the Cloud DNS servers. Tip: study how DNS works first. Small mistakes can break everything and take days to fix and resolve. Review how other hosted zones (domains) are configured. Understand how registrars work. Learn how to use DNS tools to debug. Learn public Internet tools to test your DNS settings. DNS is one service that I do not recommend "learning as you go". Learn it well first and then configure.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I understand most of it and I will keep searching, but what I understand is that the name servers are the ones who are responsible of doing the domain translation. I have name servers configured already with my domain on Squarespace. I can edit them, but the problem is that they are configured on the domain scope, not on the subdomains level. What I understand is that I have to add Google Cloud DNS nameservers with my required subdomain in Squarespace, but I see it is not applicable. Am I wrong here?

Comment: I found a solution that says I can add NS record in my registrar DNS records with my subdomain, but unfortunately there is not NS record type in Squarespace.

Comment: Go to the domain's advanced settings page. Do not add nameservers, replace them. Google Cloud DNS provides four servers. Add all of them, not just one or two. Most registrars require at least two nameservers. Tip: take screenshots of everything before making changes. Save those screenshots.

Comment: You do not need nameservers for subdomains unless you want delegated zones or have huge DNS traffic.

Comment: This link might help you: https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812058-Creating-a-subdomain-for-your-Squarespace-site I do not recommend using Squarespace DNS servers and Google Cloud DNS servers. Use one or the other but not both.